# why Erlang's Reason of termination is normal?

Tags: erlang, termination, gen-server

all

the part of log :

```
** Reason for termination == ** 
{normal,
{gen_server,call,
       [<0.9723.458>,
        {create_jtxn_mon,
            {player,34125,0,"gulexi",
```

why does it report error log when the reason is normal?
thanks for your help~~~

Comment: Hard to answer without more information. Perhaps your supervisor has a specification where the process is `permanent` but you wanted `transient` ?

Comment: Yes, definitely need more info to answer this. Who is logging? What are they logging? The original process which died with reason `normal`, or another process monitoring it which died with reason `{normal,...}`, which is **NOT** the same as plain `normal`? Was it supposed to be logging all process deaths, or just crashes? Etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you made a call to a gen_server that exited with reason `normal` before it sent a response to the caller.

In general, if a gen_server exits with reason `ServerExitReason` during a call, `gen_server:call` will exit with the exit reason `{ServerExitReason, {gen_server, call, [...]}}`, even if `ServerExitReason` is `normal`.  (See [the source](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/06067a490863cf2e7ff3323b639176b6200c9c41/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L175))

That is, the exit reason is not `normal` but `{normal, ...}`, and that's why you get a log message.